# How to launch a _bulk request with Sense for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, elasticsearch, sense

I'm beginning with ElasticSearch and Sense for Chrome (under Windows 7), and I can't launch the simple POST request (from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html). I'm getting a basic `Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):` :

`localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary "@accounts.json"`

[My screenshot of Sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNTG.png)

The `account.json` file is in my `elasticsearch/bin` directory.

The question is simple : where is my (syntax ?) error ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an instance of elasticsearch running failing to get to server at localhost:9200 indicates that.